# How does one read $\bar{A}$ aloud in Russian?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematical-russian

In English, I would generally read the mathematical notation $\bar{A}$ as "a bar" or "big a bar." What would this be in Russian?

I looked in Glazunova's *Russian for Mathematicians*, but couldn't find the answer. I found that $\bar{z}$ can be зет сопряженное, but I imagine this is only for when the bar represents conjugation.

Thanks.

Edit: I would like to clarify that I am looking for the most likely ways a mathematician would read this notation where no particular reading is suggested by the context—that is, in cases where the $\bar{\phantom{a}}$ does not represent an operation that has been given a specific name (like conjugation).

Comment: Without any context, correct reading would be "$A$ с надчёркиванием". This is rarely used, though - usually specific term for whatever the bar represents is used.

Comment: @Abstraction Okay, much appreciated!

Comment: «A с чертой» is frequently used (have never heard «A с надчеркиванием» in my life)

Comment: @GrigoryM Thanks!

Comment: Since I have received downvotes and close votes, I will point out that questions about how to read mathematical notation (in English or other languages) are on-topic: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/questions-about-how-to-read-mathematical-notation

Comment: How does one find a bar in Russia? :) Funny question. +1